# bash zip unicode option

Tags: linux, bash, unicode, utf-8

When archiving with bash zip, I want multibyte characters are encoded in UTF-8. I want to ensure path including multibyte characters extracted correctly cross platform. Say, I have files zipped on OS X and want it to be extracted correctly on Windows.

zip man instructs as below.

```
zip archive dir -r -UN=UTF8
```

"forces zip to store UTF-8 as native in the archive." ([ZIP man](http://linux.die.net/man/1/zip))

*Problem*

OS X bash shell:

```
$ zip -r test.zip tardir -UN=UTF8
zip error: Invalid command arguments (short option 'N' not supported)
```

Using long format does not help:

```
$ zip -r test.zip tardir --unicode=UTF8
zip error: Invalid command arguments (long option 'unicode' not supported)
```

Comment: AFAIK, Windows' unzip/unarchiver does not support UTF-8. Characters have to be encoded to match the user's 8bit code page. The best you can do is use `-UN=e` to escape non-ASCII chars

Comment: @AlastairMcCormack Thank you for the helpful comment.

Comment: @seongjoo Any update on this? Having the same issue.